# Using regex to find sql parameters in a string

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex expression to find SQL parameters, but it is not working under some circumstances.

```
\@([^=<>\s]+)((?=\s)|$)
```

If I use this SQL query,

```
select count(1) from (select * from tblEmailList109 where firstname='@FirstName') t
```

the value returned is:

```
@Firstname')
```

How can I modify the regex to stop stop but do not include a single quote, a space, or the end of the string?

My intention is the replace the parameter before passing it to the SQL server. I know having the single quotes in a normal stored procedure with parameters is not required, but in my case, when I do the replacement, the quotes are needed for string literals when sending to the SQL server.

Thanks

Comment: so add those inside yours regex \@([^=<>'\)\(\s]+)(|(?=\s)|$)

Comment: what do you expect `(|(?=\s)|$)` to do? or more simply, what would you expect `(|$)` to do?

Comment: Silimar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000874/get-parameter-names-from-sql-query/21272592

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add an escaped apostrophe to the list of ignores, it works for your test case.

```
\@([^=<>\s\']+)
```

Comment: That worked!  But just curious, on the look behind, it seemed like a matter or precedence.  If I used \@([^=<>\s]+)((?=\')|(?=\s)|$) it would favor the "space" as the ending delimiter instead of the single quote. Is there a way to set precedence to that if it finds the single quote first it will use that as the delimiter?

Comment: The second half of this regex does literally nothing, as I was trying to imply in my comment above

Comment: He has a point. I revised the regexp in my post to remove the redundancy, but there definitely are more elegant solutions on this page.

Answer (score 6):

Based heavily on research by Hunter McMillen, the following looks to fulfil all criteria:

```
\@([\w.$]+|"[^"]+"|'[^']+')
```

[Working example](http://regexr.com?383a3)

Your regex was capturing the trailing `')` because both of those characters are included in your character class `[^=<>\s]`

I'd also like to point out that the second half of your regex does nothing at all

```
(|(?=\s)|$)
^^
```

You have 3 alternatives (in the format `(a|b|c)`) to match here:

The middle one `(?=\s)` matches where the next character is whitespace, `$` matches end of input, but the first alternative (marked with `^^`) says match on nothing. So the alternation will always match because nothing will match between every character.

Comment: you are right, the (|(?=\s)|$) was an unfortunate typo on my part...in trying different variations I left the bar | in which made it invalid, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah fair enough, it's not the first time I've seen it posted in a regex on SO before so I assumed the worst ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what SQL you are using, but from the MySQL documentation:

> User variables are written as @var_name, where the variable name
>   var_name consists of alphanumeric characters, “.”, “_”, and “$”.
>   A user variable name can contain other characters if you quote it as a
>   string or identifier (for example, @'my-var', @"my-var", or
>   @`my-var`).

So there two possible things to check for:

1. Only alphanumeric, underscore, period and dollar sign: `\@[\w\.\$]+`
2. Anything that is quoted: \@["'`].*["'`]

The second check will return some false positives since it will match strings that don't start and end in the same quote-type, but it is simpler and your SQL editor will complain about mismatching quote-types anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I am replacing the parameters in the SQL before I send it to the SQL Server engine.

Comment: @Chris, it seems to be the case that you don't care about quoted parameters so you can literally use Hunter's `\@[\w\.\$]+` from point 1

Answer (score 2):

I would use the regex

```
@(?:[\w#_$]{1,128}|(?:(\[)|").{1,128}?(?(1)]|"))
```

It will find an `@` followed by either of these:

- Up to 128  `#`, `_`, `$`, and alphanumeric characters.
- Up to 128 characters contained within the delimiters `[]` or `""`.

You can find an full explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/nY1pR0