# Get ALL unset parameters using regex in SQL query

Tags: c#, regex

```
INSERT INTO TestTable
(
    Test1,
    Test2,
    Test3,
    Test4,
    Test5
)
VALUES
(
    @Test1,
    @Test2,
    @Test3,
    @Test4,
    @Test5
)

SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

im trying to get all the unset variables in my query this is my Regex which also gets @Id which my goal is not to include all variable that has been set on the query

this is my regex

```
Regex.Matches(sql, @"\@\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: dupe? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286674/using-regex-to-find-sql-parameters-in-a-string/21287031

Comment: No, I guess it should be `@"\B@\w+\b(?!\s*=)"`

Comment: You could extend the matching by looking for `SET` explicitly, but this doesn't cover other ways of setting variables, most notably `SELECT`, which is rather hard to match for -- meanwhile, you do not want to match things like `WHERE @i = i`, which doesn't set anything. If you want to do this reliably, using a [parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser) is your best bet; otherwise you can settle for whatever your actual queries exhibit, with the caveat that it won't be 100% reliable (as most answers currently do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
\B@\w+\b(?!\s*=)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CB%40%5Cw%2B%5Cb%28%3F!%5Cs*%3D%29&i=INSERT%20INTO%20TestTable%0D%0A%28%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Test1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Test2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Test3%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Test4%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Test5%0D%0A%29%0D%0AVALUES%0D%0A%28%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Test1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Test2%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Test3%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Test4%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Test5%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%0D%0ASET%20%40Id%20%3D%20SCOPE_IDENTITY%28%29). **Details**:

- `\B@` - match `@` not preceded with a word char (so as to avoid matching substrings like `abc@def.com`, etc.)
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\b` - word boundary (it is required to prevent backtracking when the subsequent negative lookahead fails the match, so that if the whole `@word` could be failed and so as not to return a `@wor` match)
- `(?!\s*=)` - a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are zero or more whitespaces and then a `=` char.

Note that `@` is not a special regex metacharacter and you do not need to escape it in the regular expression.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/hUUkCB):

```cs
var text = "INSERT INTO TestTable\r\n(\r\n    Test1,\r\n    Test2,\r\n    Test3,\r\n    Test4,\r\n    Test5\r\n)\r\nVALUES\r\n(\r\n    @Test1,\r\n    @Test2,\r\n\r\n    @Test3,\r\n    @Test4,\r\n\r\n    @Test5\r\n)\r\n\r\nSET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, @"\B@\w+\b(?!\s*=)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value);
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
@Test1
@Test2
@Test3
@Test4
@Test5
```

Comment: that helps! thanks im really bad at regex thanks for this answer

Comment: Have removed my answer because this is more comprehensive, but you might want to add a link to an explanation of negative lookhahead: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy Thank you, I added more details to explain the choice of subpatterns in my expressions, too.